# Trouble in detecting USB Drive (Pendrive 2.0)

Tags: usb-drive

I just bought a new pendrive  of 8gb storage. It is detected in windows but not in the Ubuntu,but the light in the pendrive still keeps flashing,so  I think the pendrive is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Not all types of partitions are automatically mounted by Ubuntu. But that doesn't mean the USB drive is not detected.

Run the following command to see all mountpoints.

```
mount
```

This will show something like

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/aditya/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=aditya)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/aditya/Aditya type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

To see device of only certain format, use

```
mount -l -t<type>
```

for example, to show only fat partitioned drives, run

```
mount -l -tvfat
```

In most cases, the last one would be the externally mounted drive.
Then run the following command to mount the drive.

```
udisks --mount /partition
```

For example

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdb1
```

To unmount

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
```

Once mounted, you should see the drive(partition) in both dash and nautilus(or your favorite file manager)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  it is an ExFat partition, so you will need to install support for it. Just do `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` and reinsert your flash drive. 
Another possibility is that your stick is NTFS formated and it was not removed safely. Just insert it into a win computer, do a scan disk ,remove it cleanly and try angain in Ubuntu. I hope it helps.